# How to return an attribute of clicked element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, buttonclick

I was wondering if there is a simple way to get an attribute of clicked element in **React.js**:

```js
function App () {
    return (
        <button
          title={'foo'}
          onClick={myFunction(this)}
         >
            click me
         </button>
    )
}

function myFunction(e) {
  alert(e.getAttribute('title')); 
}
```

Right now I'm getting: `TypeError: can't access property "getAttribute", e is undefined`.

I need it inside a function for pass the attribute into another (working) function later on.

Comment: Have you tried `e.target.getAttribute`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava unfortunately yes, it says:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: You don't need to pass `this`, it doesn't refer to the click event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the title via currentTarget

try this:

```js
function App () {
    return (
        <button
          title={'foo'}
          onClick={myFunction}
         >
            click me
         </button>
    )
}

function myFunction(e) {
  alert(e.currentTarget.title); 
}
```

Comment: Wow it's too simple :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call like this

```
<button
    title={'foo'}
    onClick={(e) => myFunction(e.currentTarget.title)}
>
   click me
</button>
```

In the function, you have to get like this.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  alert(e); // e is the value that you have pass 
}
```

Comment: `<button>` does not have `value` attribute

Answer (score 1):

`onClick={myFunction(this)}` means that the value of `onClick` prop will be set to the value that is returned by `myFunction`, i.e. `myFunction(this)` is run immediately when the code is evaluated (and not when the button is clicked). You probably want to have something like `onClick={() => myFunction(this)}` instead, so that the arrow function will be run when the button is clicked (and the arrow function will call `myFunction`).

However, `this` is `undefined`, as seen from the error message you got ("e is undefined"), hence you get the error (`undefined` doesn't have a property called "getAttribute").

You can pass the event object to `myFunction` like this:

```js
onClick={(e) => myFunction(e)}
```

Then you can access the `button` element with `e.currentTarget` and then get the `title` attribute:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  alert(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('title')); 
}
```