# How do I pass the ID of the button pressed to the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child

I'm trying to create a simple **component** that displays a group of buttons such that when one of the buttons is pressed, the parent knows the ID of that button. I have written some code, but I'm stuck as to the final step to identify which of the buttons is pressed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
function GroupofButtons(props) {
  const groupofBtns = [];
  props.btns.forEach((btn) => {
    groupofBtns.push(<button id={btn} value={btn} key={btn} onClick={() => props.onClick()}>{btn}</button>)
    }
  );
 
  return(
    <>
      {groupofBtns}
    </>
  )
}

function App() {
  // How can the console show the id of the button that was pressed
  const handleClick  = () => console.log("pressed");
  const btn_typs = [1,2,3,];
  return (
    <>Press a button!
      <div>
        <GroupofButtons btns={btn_typs} onClick={() => handleClick()}/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return an attribute of clicked element in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743418/how-to-return-an-attribute-of-clicked-element-in-react)

Comment: You need to pass it in as an argument to the child's `onClick`, e.g. `onClick={() => props.onClick(btn)}` and then in the parent, where you define that function, define a parameter as well: `const handleClick  = (btn) => console.log(btn);`

Comment: @Jayce444 - thanks for the tip - I did try that and the log shows 'undefined' - I assume the problem is related somehow to the way that I've broken out the child

Comment: @jaesle just saw how you passed it down, yes that's causing the issue. If something is a function you can just pass it directly. So when rendering GroupofButtons, pass the prop like this: `onClick={handleClick}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const btn_typs = [1, 2, 3];
export default function App() {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name);
  };

  return (
    <>
      Press a button!
      <div>
        <GroupofButtons btns={btn_typs} handleClick={handleClick} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function GroupofButtons(props) {
  return props.btns.map((btn, i) => (
    <button name={btn} key={i} onClick={props.handleClick}>
      {btn}
    </button>
  ));
}
```

Heres the codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-firefly-czvct?file=/src/App.js